# docker.exe: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Tags: git, maven, powershell, docker

Powershell:

### Input

PS `C:\git> docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v {$pwd}:/usr/src/mymaven -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:3.3-jdk-8 mvn clean install`

### Output

> C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: invalid
>   reference format: repository name must be lowercase. See 'C:\ProgramFiles\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.

Answer (score 4):

I think the following is causing the problem: `{$pwd}`.

As documented on [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/maven/), try using the command as follows:

```
docker run -it --rm --name my-maven-project -v "$PWD":/usr/src/mymaven -w /usr/src/mymaven maven:3.3-jdk-8 mvn clean install
```